# Google Analytics is not tracking our social media conversions properly because our Paypal payment gateway

Tags: google-analytics, ecommerce, magento, paypal, payment-gateway

I'm trying to track what transactions are coming from social media advertising campaigns, however due to the set up of our existing site (Magento) which goes through a Paypal gateway. All transactions seem to be originating from Paypal.

I need to figure out a way around this, I've tried to set up a goal that works using complete check out and segments as well but cannot seem to break down which social media platform is responsible for these sales.

I also need to be able to see the transaction ID inside the eCommerce tab of Google Analytics.

Answer (score 1):

Google Analytics has a solution for this: [Referral Exclusions](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2795830?hl=en).   You can set up Google Analytics to treat referrals from Paypal such that they don't start new sessions.   When users come back to your site after paying, they will then continue their existing session.

> #### Third-party payment processors
>
> A common use for this feature is to prevent third-party shopping carts from starting second sessions. When the third-party shopping cart is in the exclusion list, a user will no longer initiate a new session, and won't be counted as a referral when they return to your order-confirmation page after checking out on the third-party site.

Comment: Hello Stephen,

Would doing this method show me where the sales are coming from in regards to social media platform? I need to be able to track if transaction '12345' came from Twitter for example. I also need to be able to see the transaction details in the eCommerce section?

Comment: Assuming that you [tag your campaign landing URLs with UTM parameters](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?hl=en) this will allow you to track sales back to the correct campaigns.     I don't know anything about adding transaction ids to the ecommerce report, I only know how to solve the Paypal problem.